# How to Clear Selected date ranges when i click on reset button in android calender listview

Tags: android, android-calendar

In my application i've implemented a calendar view to select date range. That working fine but I want to reset the selection date when click on reset button. I'm using onDateRangeSelected() method for selection of date range.

Used this source code for getting CalendarView: [CalendarView Code](https://github.com/traex/CalendarListview)

Please Help me if anyone knows about this functionality.

**Here is the required screen.**

[image: required screen screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling `mAdapter.setSelectedDay(null);` from setController method.
it will clear the selected date ranges .
hope it will help you #happycoding.

Comment: Thank you very much.. it's working fine. you saved my time

Answer (score 0):

Try reinitializing your calendar view using `init()` method as it is the public method and it will initialize your view.

You can check the source [here](https://github.com/traex/CalendarListview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/andexert/calendarlistview/library/DayPickerView.java).

Comment: Yes, i tried just now, but not clear the dates range

Comment: try calling `dayPickerView.setController(this);` and check if it resets your view.

Comment: yes bro i tried this one also but it is not reset the clenderview .. really stucked with this isuue

Comment: Then you can raise the issue over github and check with the developer. if you can compile and add library as module in your project then your can set your adapter to null, currently it is accessed using protected methods that you will not be able to call.

Comment: yes i raised on github isuues , but developer not responding for previous issues also. might be he'll not available

Comment: then you can compile and add library as a module in your project.

Comment: when i set null as adapter it is not even showing calender list.. it is just showing empty screen